# Maven: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$CodeGenerationException

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu

Whenever I try to build any maven project or generate some archetype, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$CodeGenerationException
[ERROR] Caused by: com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$CodeGenerationException
[ERROR] Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException
```

Maven used to work ok just yesterday, and don't remember changing anything in its' configurations lately. I use jdk8 oracle and jdk7 openjdk on Ubuntu 14.04 (I switch between 2 javas from time to time using Ubuntu's update-alternative --config javac).

If I run

```
mvn -B archetype:generate   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes   -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app   -DartifactId=my-app -X
```

I get this output:

```
username@pcname:~/Desktop/projects/mvn_simple$ mvn -B archetype:generate   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes   -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app   -DartifactId=my-app -X
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-40-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$CodeGenerationException
    at com.google.common.collect.MapMaker$ComputingMapAdapter.get(MapMaker.java:890)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:530)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:179)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:123)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:470)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:196)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$CodeGenerationException
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.apply(FailableCache.java:38)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:356)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:182)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:151)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:67)
    at com.google.common.collect.MapMaker$ComputingMapAdapter.get(MapMaker.java:886)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: I faced similar kind of issue with error: `ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper `. The issue at my end was, I was trying to build with `>mvn clean install ` in command-line. My project was in IntelliJ workspace with adding multiple repos as modules. But I opened up the command-line with  with right click the module. After did the build with normal command-line it worked without errors

Comment: Just identified the RC for the above which was, incorrect JDK version in the environmental  variable set for that particular command-line session.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Restarting PC solved the problem :)

Comment: turning off and turning it on always be a solution for random problem

Comment: This is not always the issue, the main reason can be conflicting java/mvn versions.

Answer (score 28):

As of 2021/10/25, the maven 3.6.x package in Ubuntu is not working properly with Java 17.

Create `vi ~/.mavenrc` file and give any version lower than 17.

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/`

If you wish to upgrade to 3.8.x for java 17. https://m-thirumal.github.io/installation_guide/maven/upgrade_maven/

(or as already suggested earlier install your java related tools using [sdkman.io](https://sdkman.io))

Comment: Maven 3.6.3 does not work with Java 17, but upgrading to maven 3.8.3 works for me.

Comment: Maven 3.6.3 works with Java 17 on my laptop and on my servers.

Comment: I downloaded `apache-maven-3.8.5-bin.tar.gz` from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi, extracted the folder, `sudo mv`'d it to `/opt` and `sudo ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.8.5/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn`. It worked.

Comment: This is an [ubuntu specific issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72879695/6346531), using `sdk install maven 3.6.3` if maven upgradation is not  an option/priority also works.

Answer (score 5):

For me the issue was due to the fact that in my pom.xml Java 13 was mentioned, on the server machine java 17 was installed.

So updated server java version to be what it is in pom.xml
If you have multiple versions of JDK on Linux please use this command to choose the correct one

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Choose correct JDK version, if your version is not listed install it and uset it to be active JDK using above command, after that do a clean build and run

```
 mvn clean install
 mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be caused by Ubuntu using the non no_aop version of guice.jar in maven 3.6.3 (which needs the no_aop guice.jar).

As a workaround in Ubuntu you could (if you don't care breaking some other ubuntu package actually needing the non no_aop jar):

```bash
sudo wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/4.2.1/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar -O /usr/share/java/guice.jar
```

But it should be better and safer to use an official maven release directly

https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/

instead of the Ubuntu packaged one. (as an alternative install maven using [sdkman.io](https://sdkman.io))

P.S. Ubuntu seems to be trying to share jars between different java packages by putting and linking different jars under /usr/shara/java/ - a noble effort, but an insane approach)

Comment: This is the best solution if maven upgradation is not  an option/priority. This can be done conveniently via sdkman using `sdk install maven 3.6.3`

Comment: This is the best solution if you don't want to break/fix something else.

Answer (score 3):

As *André Willik Valenti* mentioned, replacing the maven package with the latest version solves the problem, the steps I did:

1- Download the latest Maven version:

```
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.9.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.9.4-bin.tar.gz
```

2- Extract the downloaded package:

```
tar -xvf apache-maven-3.9.4-bin.tar.gz
```

3- Enter into the extracted folder:

```
cd apache-maven-3.9.4
```

4- Delete the previous Maven files:

```
sudo rm -R -f  /usr/share/maven/*
```

5- Move the extracted package to previous Maven installation:

```
sudo mv * /usr/share/maven
```

6- Verify installation:

```
mvn -version
```

UPDATE:
The above maven version has been updated to 3.9.4 due to the removal of previous version

Good Luck

Comment: This worked with WIn 11 / OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-wsl2/ openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18  / Apache Maven 3.8.7 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the Maven version you are using does not support the Java version you installed.

I fixed the issue by installing the latest version of Maven using SDK man:

```sh
sdk install maven
```

Source: https://sdkman.io/sdks#maven

Comment: I have fixed in the same way `# apt install maven`

Answer (score 1):

Try a different java version.

To me after some upgrade it had switch to use Java 16 over 11.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the order of the path variable is causing the problem.

```
PATH=$PATH:$M2 - Causing the error
PATH=$M2:$PATH - Solve the problem
```

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

set all required version on all environments like java etc

then restart machine will solve the problem.