# Error executing Maven for Lombok with Java 17

Tags: java, maven, lombok

```
$ mvn clean package
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
[ERROR] Caused by: Exception com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2d127a61 [in thread "main"]
```

I was expecting a normal build.

I'm using Maven 3.6.3 and Lombok 1.18.30.

IntelliJ IDEA can build & run the project without any problems using `openjdk-17-jdk`, so it's not the JDK API problem I think.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The error suggests you're using something which doesn't support Java 17.

Comment: Do you use the latest version of lombok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of Maven 3.9.6 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij actually comes with its own packaged Maven installation and it should be up-to-date of your specific Intellij version. That is why you have no problems running on Intellij but have problems running your commands on the command line.

[image]

The solution, as you have found, is to update your Maven installation and to update the path to point to the new Maven because your current version of Maven is likely not compatible with Java 17. Here is a link to an excellent answer for steps on how to properly update your Maven installation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199477/16034206